# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

Tags: maven, cassandra, datastax, maven-dependency

I have a maven project A

pom.xml for the project A :

```
<dependencies>
       <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.app.cops</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-logging</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

pom.xml of the project cassandra-logging:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

The cops-logging projecct has the following code :

```
CassandraCopsComponentLogger.instance = new CassandraCopsComponentLogger();

                String hosts = CassandraClientUtil.getHost();
                String localDC = CassandraClientUtil.getLocalDC();
                Cluster cluster;
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(localDC))
                {
                    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts.split(","))
                            .withCredentials(CassandraCopsComponentLogger.USER_NAME, CassandraCopsComponentLogger.AUTH_CODE)
                            .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE))
                            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().withLocalDc(localDC).build())).build();
                }
                else
                {
                    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts.split(","))
                            .withCredentials(CassandraCopsComponentLogger.USER_NAME, CassandraCopsComponentLogger.AUTH_CODE)
                            .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE)).build();
                }

                Session session = cluster.connect();
                CassandraCopsComponentLogger.mappingManager = new MappingManager(session);
```

I keep on getting exception on the following line :

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts.split(","))
```

I have a unit test in cassandra-logging project which works fine with this code. But when I call the same code from project A I get the

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
```

Comment: Your setting seems fine. Was your build on Project A successful?

Comment: Yes. The Project A was able to build successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by downgrading the cassandra dependency version to `<version>2.1.9</version>`. Not sure how that helped but I was able to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Update the version of cassandra-driver-core and cassandra-driver-mapping to 3.3.0 - this worked for me:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. The error i got was :

```
Factory method 'sqlSession' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/oss/protocol/internal/SegmentCodec
```

relevant pom.xml segment:

```xml
<properties>
..
<oss-java-driver.version>4.9.0</oss-java-driver.version>
..
</properties>
..
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>${oss-java-driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-query-builder</artifactId>
    <version>${oss-java-driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Solution that worked for me : I have to explicitly declare dependency on native-protocol to override the version of native-protocol.

```xml
<properties>
..
<cassandra-native-protocol.version>1.4.11</cassandra-native-protocol.version>
..
</properties>
..
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-protocol</artifactId>
    <version>${cassandra-native-protocol.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Reference : https://community.datastax.com/answers/8185/view.html